# PHP variable globlization issue

Tags: php, oop, scope

I have a public object Let say X. defined in a config file. How could I use this object in a method within a class. I think when I globalize X in that method its looks within the class.
:(

```
include('config.php'); //the objec X is defined here
class MyClass{
 public foo(){
 global $X; // I thing It is looking within the class
 }
}
```

Comment: So, you can't make use of $x in the foo() method now? Is this local or on a webserver? Is it working outside the class?

Comment: No, It is in global scope, So you can use it in your method.

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code inside of config.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a demo...I hope this is what you wanted..
global.php

```
<?php

$x=5;

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
include('global.php');
class foo{
private $value;
function __construct(){
global $x;
    $this->value=$x;
}
function show(){
    return $this->value;
}
}
$a= new foo();
echo $a->show();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
class LemonSalesman {
    public function advertise() {
        echo 'Get your fresh lemons here!';
    }
}

$LemonSalesman = new LemonSalesman();

class MyObject {
    public function foo() {
        global $LemonSalesman;

        $LemonSalesman->advertise();
    }
}

$MyObject = new MyObject();
$MyObject->foo();
```

Are you sure your $X object is global?

Answer (score 0):

If you defined `$x` in your config file in this way:

```
 <?php
      $x = 'somevalue';
 ?>
```

then using the `global` in the function will work just fine. Alternately you could also use the global array to access the variable `$GLOBALS['x']`, however I'm not sure how common or suggested that is.

However, if you have your configuration variable defined inside a function or class then it would have to have a global there as well for example:

```
 <?php

      function loadConfig(){
           // no global here means that $x is not global.
           $x = 'somevalue';
      }
 <?
```